# How to use My WebService From Out of Local machin in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, webmethod

i write a Web Service.asmx to provide a dollar price service for other sites.
but when i publish  it into my website and go for test it i receive this exception :

**The test form is only available for requests from the local machine.**

I Use code below in my asmx file:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Services
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class Services : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

[WebMethod]

public string USD_Prices()
{
    string UnitedStateDollar;
    using (var Entity = new DataModel.DBEntities())
    {
        var UsdPrice = Entity.TblExchange.OrderByDescending(Exchange => Exchange.Id).Select(p => p.USDSell).Take(1).ToList();
        UnitedStateDollar = UsdPrice[0].ToString();
    }
    return UnitedStateDollar;
}
```

}

So what is the problem?....and if you Want to check it online the address is :

http://www.nerkhyab.ir/services.asmx

Comment: How about creating a test client and adding your service as a reference?

Comment: @amin Please Go through this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819267

Comment: @SurajSingh Thanks my friend.....your refer documantion solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your web config.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Check [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;819267) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yx7be39%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: This wasn't done for security reasons (the form worked only on the local machine). This was done because real-world web services have complex parameters that can't be handled by a simple form

Comment: There's no error to correct. This is a simple demo form that isn't meant for real use. The clients of the web service need to add a service reference to the service's endpoint to call it

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem. Web services don't have forms. In order to use a web service from .NET,  you add the as a service references and call them from client code.

Old-style ASMX services had a form you could use for demonstration purposes where you could enter some simple values and call POST to get a result from the service. This was removed in WCF services because real-world web services have complex parameters that can't be handled by a simple form.

It would be far better to create a WCF service instead of an ASMX service. WCF services are more compliant, performant, flexible, scaleable (etc etc).

In any case, you can call you service from another client by adding a Service Reference to your project. This will create a proxy class that will expose the service's parameters as objects and the endpoints as methods on a client object.

Comment: Ok...But how a bout PHP?
There is another web site in PHP which want to use my site webservice to recive the USD Price...As i said please